# PreferenceFragment - how to remove line between items?

Tags: line, preferencefragment

How can I remove the horizontal line below the fields(red)?

Also i want to know, how i can insert an horizontal line between the categories(blue)?

settings.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_ankunft_abflug"
            android:layout="@layout/styles1">

        <com.example.world.DatePickerPreference
            android:key="prefVon"
            android:layout="@layout/styles1"
            android:summary="@string/pref_datum_von" />

        <com.example.world.DatePickerPreference
            android:key="prefBis"
            android:layout="@layout/styles1"
            android:summary="@string/pref_datum_bis"/>

        <com.example.world.DatePickerPreference
            android:key="prefBis"
            android:layout="@layout/styles1"
            android:summary="@string/pref_datum_bis"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory>
        <Preference
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dip"
            android:background="@color/texte" />

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="10"
            android:entries="@array/Vorschläge"
            android:entryValues="@array/VorschlägeValues"
            android:key="prefUmkreis"
            android:layout="@layout/styles1"
            android:summary="@string/pref_umkreis_titel"
            android:title="@string/pref_umkreis"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

styles1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/ueberschrift"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/texte"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Picture:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3629/h4kczzxv_png.htm